# Entity SQL selecting from more then 3 tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I am new to Entity framwork and currently trying hard to get used this programming paradigm. I have this query which i want to write in Entity SQL.

```
SELECT      f.id,  f.personName,   c.Category,    j.busCode,    s.description,         f.StartDate, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Analysis WHERE id = f.id) As numOfAnalysis
FROM forms f
INNER JOIN Jobs j  ON f.id = j.id
INNER JOIN category c  ON j.categoryid = c.categoryid
INNER JOIN stage s  ON f.stageid = s.stageid
WHERE j.busCode NOT IN ('xyz', 'YYY')
ORDER BY startDate
```

I can get records from two tables but as soon as i add third table using the navigation property, i get error table category is not loaded in the current context. I am using .net 3.5. Keep in mind that EDM V2 doest not have foreign keys and i think the only way to traverse through the table relationship is navigation property.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Coder74

Comment: Why don't you show us your code? How could we possibly guess the reason for this message?

Comment: In addition to the above comment - why do you need to use Entity SQL instead Linq To Entities?

Comment: If you use .Net 3.5 linq-to-sql may be a better choice. But then, navigation properties is not the only way. You can always use the linq join statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use should be able to mount this Linq query.
I tried to put together, but in the rush and no such test is complicated.
You can use this reference as support: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

```
var result  = (from f in forms
            join j in Jobs on f.id equals j.id
            join c in Category on j.categoryid equals c.categoryid
            join s in stage on f.stageid equals s.stageid
            join a in Analysis on a.id equals f.id
            where !(new int[] { 'xyz', 'YYY' }).Contains(j.busCode)
            orderby f.StartDate
            select {
                id =f.id,
                personName = f.personName,   
                Category = c.Category,
                busCode = j.busCode,
                description = s.description,
                StartDate = f.StartDate, 
                numOfAnalysis = a.Count()
            }).ToList()
```

Julio Spader

W&S Soluções de Internet